# I observed that a duplicate request was sent 60 seconds following the first request, yet the browser's devtool displays only a single request

Tags: http, browser, wireshark

I use axios to perform the request, here is an example of my codes:

```js
const abort = new AbortController()
const res = await axios.get('/rl/dev/network/status', { signal: abort.signal })
// ...
```

Sometimes the backend will take more than 60 seconds to respond, and I can see a duplicate request was sent in wireshark

| No. | Time | Source | Destination | Protocol | Length | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 2.530103 | 192.168.20.10 | 192.168.20.1 | HTTP | 448 | GET /rl/dev/network/status HTTP/1.1 |
| 526 | 62.468953 | 192.168.20.10 | 192.168.20.1 | HTTP | 448 | GET /rl/dev/network/status HTTP/1.1 |

But in the F12 devtool only display the first request.

Where does the second request come from?

Thanks for answering, and I am not an English native speaker, forgive me if there are any wrong grammar in my sentences

Looking for how to avoid the duplicate request